# How can create own call function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, call

As of my knowledge, in javascript there are three concepts; call, apply and bind
I want to create these function with similar behavior.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Please explain exactly what you are trying to do.  What do you want to do differently from those methods that you list?  It is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: i want to know internal behavior of these because some ask me in paytm interview

Comment: @JonasW. but not `call()` They have a polyfill for `bind()` but it depends on `apply()`

Comment: @zero298 This is a famous interview question to check your JS skills

Comment: @SuryaprakashPatel Check out my reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your own call function like "_call"

```
Function.prototype._call = function(newcontext, ...arg){

var demoFn = new Function('tempfuncton', 'tempthis','arg' , '{ tempthis["f"]=tempfuncton; return tempthis.f(arg);}');
demoFn(this,newcontext,arg);
}
```

write a demo function

```
function anyfunction(args){
console.log(this,args)
}
```

call it like previous. First argument should be an object. Otherwise write a code to convert it into object.

```
anyfunction._call({'mm':'my provided this object'},"arg1","arg2")
```

Comment: How creating own function call here is different from your previous answer?

Comment: And also why did you feel the need to put a bounty on this? There are a ton of resources about call/bind/apply online.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a polyfill for them (not accurate though, just what came into my mind):

```
Function.prototype.call = function(context, ...args) {
  const fn = Symbol();
  try {
    context[fn] = this; 
    return context[fn](...args);
   } catch(e) {
      // Turn primitive types into complex ones 1 -> Number, thanks to Mark Meyer for this.
     context = new context.constructor(context);
     context[fn] = this;
  }
  return context[fn](...args);
};

Function.prototype.apply = function(context, args) {
  return this.call(context, ...args);
};

Function.prototype.bind = function(context, ...args) {
  return (...args2) => this.call(context, ...args, ...args2);
};
```

*The only thing that is impossible to polyfill is `fn.call(null)`, as that primitive can't be turned into a complex type, only native code can do this*

Comment: Please explain Symbol().

Comment: @mukund https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

Comment: @JonasW. funny…I deleted, because I though I confused something, but maybe not.

Comment: Glad I found this. Just one remark: I had to add a return in front of context[fn](...args) in order to make the call replacement work.

Comment: Can you explain the lines `context[fn] = this;
return context[fn](...args);`?

Comment: @JonasWilms Can someone explain this?`// Turn primitive types into complex ones 1 -> Number, thanks to Mark Meyer for this.
     context = new context.constructor(context);`

Answer (score 2):

```
function B(a,b,c){
   console.log(a,b,c)
}

Function.prototype.OwnCallFunction = function(){  
    if( this.length == arguments.length)
        this(...arguments)
    else
        console.error('Signature does not match')
 } 
B.OwnCallFunction(323,34,34)
```

I followed this approach to create own call function. With help of Function
Constructor, I add a function to it and it worked on firefox.

> New approach, with more clarity

```
Function.prototype.call2 = function(context, ...args){
    console.log(context)
    const fn = Symbol();
    context[fn] = this; 
    context[fn](...args);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `call` take `this` as a first argument?

Comment: @Mark Please suggest more better way to me.

Comment: I don't know a way to do this off the top of my head without using one of the other functions, but if it is to work like `call()` it needs to be able to bind `this` to an object passed into the first argument.

Comment: it depends on definition of B, how many arguments it will take.

Answer (score 1):

In above answers I can see that spread operators has been used, but if we really want to make pollyfill of call then we should avoid spread
operator and latest concept of es6.I am sharing solution without es6.

Call Function:-

```
Function.prototype.myCall = function(obj) {
   obj = obj || global;
   var id = "00" + Math.random();
  while (obj.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    id = "00" + Math.random();
  }
  obj[id] = this;
  let arg=[];
  for(let i=1;i<arguments.length;i++){
       arg.push("arguments[" + i + "]");
  }
 result= eval("obj[id]("+arg+")");
  delete obj[id];
  return result;
}
```

Apply function:-

```
Function.prototype.myApply = function(obj, argArr) {
 obj = obj || global;
 var id = "00" + Math.random();
 while (obj.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
  id = "00" + Math.random();
 }
 obj[id] = this;
 let arg=[];
 let result
 if(!argArr){
  result= obj[id].fn();
 }
 else{
  for(let i=0;i<argArr.length;i++){
      arg.push("argArr[" + i + "]");
     }
  result= eval("obj[id]("+arg+")");
  delete obj[id];
}
return result;
```

}

Bind function:-

```
Function.prototype.myBind2= function(){
  let obj1= this;
  const obj= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0,1);
   const arg= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1);
  return function(){
    const arg2= Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
   obj1.apply(obj[0],Array.prototype.concat(arg, arg2));
}
```

Another solution Bind: we can pass object argument of function

```
Function.prototype.myBind2 = function(obj) {
  let fn = this;
  const arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  return function() {
    const arg2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    fn.apply(obj, Array.prototype.concat(arg, arg2));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While each browser has its own source code for implementing Javascript, you can find how many of the native Javascript functions are implemented with the ECMA specifications found here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object

For specs of `apply`, see: 19.2.3.1

For specs of `bind`, see: 19.2.3.2

For specs of `call`, see: 19.2.3.3

If you're interested for example, how Node implemented `apply`, you can dig into their source code on Github here: https://github.com/nodejs/node

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sweet and simple solution. We are adding the ObjRef in prototypal chain to avoid any name conflicts with other properties

```
    Function.prototype.call2 = function (objRef, ...args) {
      otherObj = Object.create(objRef)
      otherObj[this.name] = this;
      otherObj[this.name](...args);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using `Object.create` makes sense here as when you will console `this` inside the function you won't see the desired object.
Here is my try(not accurate though) but will work.

```
Function.prototype.myCall = function (thisContext, ...param) {
    let name = this.name;
    thisContext[name] = this;
    thisContext[name](...param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Function.prototype.mycall = function(context, ...args){
    context.fun= this; //add personal function to context  
    context.fun(...args);
  }
  
  function personal (msg){
    alert(this.name + " " + msg);
  }
  
  let obj = {
    name:'Ajinkya'
  }
  
  personal.mycall(obj,'Khandar'); // pass object and args in mycall
```

[image]